# how to remove key value and extract only the contents inside the key value?

Tags: python

this is my current code.

```
       mentaldict = {}
    mentaldict["Progressive Forgetfulness or Known Cognitive impairment"] = mentallist[0]
    mentaldict["Progressive Forgetfulness or Known Cognitive impairment Status Details"] = mentallist[1]
    mentaldict["Depression"] = mentallist[2]
    mentaldict["Depression Status Details"] = mentallist[3]
    mentaldict["Sleep Issues"] = mentallist[4]
    mentaldict["Sleep Issues Status Details"] = mentallist[5]
    mentaldict["Behavioral Disturbance"] = mentallist[6]
    mentaldict["Behavioral Disturbance Status Details"] = mentallist[7]
    mentaldict["Cognitive History"] = [mentallist[8], mentallist[9]]
```

the output of the code is

```
'Progressive Forgetfulness or Known Cognitive impairment': 'No',
'Progressive Forgetfulness or Known Cognitive impairment Status Details':'very alert', 
'Depression': 'No', 
'Depression Status Details': 'very sad',
'Suicide risk: 'No', 
'Sleep Issues': 'No',
'Sleep Issues Status Details': 'barely sleeps'
'Behavioral Disturbance': 'Yes', 
'Behavioral Disturbance Status Details': 'Wife claims he is OCD.',
'Cognitive History':'very forgetful'
```

i only want my output to display the contents of the key value pair, such as

```
'No', 'very alert', 'No', 'very sad', 'No', 'barely sleeps', 'Yes', 'Wife claims he is OCD.','very forgetful'
```

i have tried using returnedvalue but it only returns for one variable

Comment: Where is the code that outputs the data?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to obtain the values of the keys, you can use:

```
print mentaldict.keys() # it return a list with values of de dictionary
# Output
# ['very sad', 'No', 'Wife claims he is OCD.', 'very alert', 'No', 'very 
forgetful', 'barely sleeps', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']
```

If you only want to obtain the values of the dictionary, you can use:

```
print mentaldict.values() # it return a list with values of de dictionary
# Output
# ['very sad', 'No', 'Wife claims he is OCD.', 'very alert', 'No', 'very 
forgetful', 'barely sleeps', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']
```

If you want to obtain both you can use:

```
print mentaldict.items() # it return a list of tubles like (key,value) 
# Output
# [('Depression Status Details', 'very sad'), ('Sleep Issues', 'No'), ('Behavioral Disturbance Status Details', 'Wife claims he is OCD.'), ('Progressive Forgetfulness or Known Cognitive impairment Status Details', 'very alert'), ('Suicide risk', 'No'), ('Cognitive History', 'very forgetful'), ('Sleep Issues Status Details', 'barely sleeps'), ('Progressive Forgetfulness or Known Cognitive impairment', 'No'), ('Depression', 'No'), ('Behavioral Disturbance', 'Yes')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .values() method of dictionnary.

```
print(", ".join([i for i in mentaldict.values()]))
```